# How do I get a ListView beside a GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, layout

I have a `ListView` which I want to display to the left of a `GridView`. I used the following xml code to attempt to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView_items">
</ListView>
<GridView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/gridView_board"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listView_items">
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Problematically, only the `ListView` appears when the activity is launched. I realize this is simple, but I haven't coded in a long while and was unable to find helpful information using Google.

Thanks!

Comment: You used android:layout_width="match_parent" on both of your ListView and GridView which is why the ListView occupies first all the width of the parentview which is the RelativeLayout. Try using a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and set a weightSum of 2 then for the GridView and ListView set their weight into 1 and layout_width into 0dp. That should do the trick.

Comment: @KaHeL That did indeed do it. Thanks! If you would like to post your comment as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You used `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on both of your `ListView` and `GridView` which is why the `ListView` occupies first all the width of the parentview which is the `RelativeLayout`.

Change the `RelativeLayout` into `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and set a `weightSum` of 2 then for the `GridView` and `ListView` set their weight into 1 and layout_width into 0dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_items"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</ListView>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_board"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```